# How to set a constraint on swift protocol for adopting type?

Tags: swift, constraints, protocols

I need to make a multistage tokenizer in swift and for this purpose I decided to make a protocol that requires adopter of this protocol to be a sequence of characters. Like that

```swift
protocol TokenProtocol where Self: Sequence, Self.Item == Character {
    //any token must consist of characters
    var characterRepresentation: [Character] { get }
    //but not all tokens may consist of multiple words 
    var wordRepresentaion: [String]? { get }
}
```

But it raise a compilation error that `'Item' is not a member type of 'Self'`
Am I doing this in a wrong way? What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Self.Item` with `Self.Element`.